# Should Parcel.writeSerializable be used in a Parcelable.writeToParcel?

Tags: android

I am new to android and am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around the Parcelable interface.

I eventually found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/6647053

The point made in the above answer is that when passing an object to an activity, this:

```
intent.putExtra("object", parcelableObject);
```

performs much better than this:

```
intent.putExtra("object", serializableObject);
```

My question is: 
Would there be any performance benefit to using a Parcel's read / write Serializable methods within the Parcelable (as opposed to just using a serializable object with intent.putExtra)? Why / Why not?

Example:

```
public class MyParcelable implements Serializable, Parcelable {

    /* Some Custom Object Stuff Here */

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeSerializable(this);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
        public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return parcel.readSerializable();
        }

        public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyParcelable[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit to writing this: parceling will be as slow as serializing.

In ordinary Java, `Externalizable` can perform better than `Serializable`, because you supply your own `readExternal(ObjectInput in)` and `writeObject(ObjectOutput out)` in which you are expected to manually serialize your fields instead of relying on the JVM to introspect and automatically do it for you. Android's `Parcelable` serves a similar purpose.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.